# Imbalance conjecture

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a finite simple undirected graph. For an edge $e=uv$ of $G$, its *imbalance* is the number $imb(e):=|d(u)-d(v)|$ where $d(u)$ is the degree of a vertex $u$ of $G$. Denote by $M_G$ the multiset of all edge imbalances of the graph $G$.

Prove or disprove the following

> **Imbalance Conjecture.** *Suppose that $imb(e)\ge 1$ for every edge $e$ of $G$. Then $M_G$ is graphic.*

A multiset is *graphic* if it is equal to the multiset of vertex degrees of some graph (such multisets are characterized by [the Erdos-Gallai Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Gallai_theorem)).

---

This problem was posed on 27 August 2021 by Sergiy Kozerenko (from Kyiv Mohyla Academy) on page [92](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka/viewpage.php?vol=3&page=92) of [Volume 3](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka/viewbook.php?vol=3) of [Lviv Scottish Book](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka/view.php).